# jquery mouseover animation jumping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table which is looped in `<li>`. On mouseover each row, there will be a border shown, and the row id="resFunc" will be displayed. However, in IE, the animation jumps up and down.

Anyone has similar experience or solution to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="resDetails" align="left">
          <table width="400px" class="resBox">
            <tr>
              <td><b>{creator}</b></td>          
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><div class="edit{_id}" id="{_id}"> {title}</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none" class="url{_id}">
               <td colspan="2" class="edit_url{_id}" id="{_id}">{url}</td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="edit_area{_id}" id="{_id}">{description}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="resFunc{_id}" style="display:none">
              <td colspan="2" align="right"><b><a href="#" id="{_id}" class="editRes">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" class="deleteResource" id="{_id}">Delete</a></b>
               </td>
             </tr>
          </table><br>
        </div>
```

This is the onClick function :-

```
$(".resBox").mouseover(function(){ 
var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
$(this).addClass('highlight');  
$('#resFunc'+id).show();
}); 

$(".resBox").mouseout(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$(this).removeClass('highlight');
$('#resFunc'+id).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [.mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [.mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseeleave/) a shot.

```
$(".resBox").mouseenter(function(){ 
 var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
 $(this).addClass('highlight');  
 $('#resFunc'+id).show();
}); 

$(".resBox").mouseleave(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr("id");
 $(this).removeClass('highlight');
 $('#resFunc'+id).hide();
});
```

Explanation:

.mouseover() will fire every time you move the cursor over the element, whereas .mouseenter only fires once, you guessed correctly, when the cursor is entering the target element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :) I managed to solve it by using your suggestion, and enclose the row with another div which will detects mouseover and mouseout. I still need the mouseover and mouseout. Without it, the animation works only once for my multiple table which is looped. 
Thanks, will not be able to solve it without the help from you guys!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using [mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), might help.

Also you could test how many times your mouse over is being called by adding `alert('mouse over called');` or console.log

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have yet to try, but mouseenter and mouseleave does solve the issue , with additional <div> of mouseover and mouseout (because my table is a loop). 
Thanks, will not be able to solve this without your help :)

Comment: Something that may save you some headscratching in the future, if you start writing complex jquery functions that call each other, if you put 'console.log("function abc called!")' at the beginning of each function, and view with firebug, you can check everything is called in the correct order, the right amount of times!   note console.log breaks in IE

Comment: Thanks Haroldo for the tip! Very useful :)